# How to speed up rendering of transparent areas?

Tags: rendering, transparency, compositing-nodes

This is a bit of a trick question. **We know that HOLDOUT will subtract objects from renders**. My question is slightly more elaborate. I had a render that I spent a fair amount of money on (render farm), only to find out that a material was set to the wrong settings. So I'm re-rendering the animation with every other object *BUT* the one I need using the **HOLDOUT** feature.

However, Blender is crawling all over the rendering even though 80% of the frame is 100% transparent. I'd love a way to have Blender only render the area where the object exists. I know about setting a render area method, but the problem arises where I need the object to be in the EXACT location that its predecessor was that had the material problem, so rendering the entire 4k frame is very helpful for a clean overlay.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Since 2.9 there's *adaptive sampling* available. It should make transparent areas render very fast, since they don't need any samples.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had seen this but didn't realize it affected this area. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks! I hadn't twigged to that, either.

Comment: This took rendering times from 45 mins to 12 mins. Really amazing. Thank you again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since 2.9 you can enable *Adaptive Sampling*.
Transparent areas (or pure HDRI) are then rendered with 1 sample only.

[image]

Comment: I had problems with 2.9.x corrupting my objects, so I pulled back to 2.8.3.6. I'm now using copies of my files to simply render. This was the key! 2.75 hour renders down to 30 mins.